# Namespaces and Class names with underscores

Tags: php, laravel-4

composer.json contains the following

```
...
"autoload": {
    ...
    "psr-0":{"Acme": "app/lib"}
},
```

at app/lib/Acme/Models/Product/Display.php I have the following:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Models\Product;
use Eloquent;
use Db;
class Product_Display extends Eloquent 
{
```

I'm lost on how to call that class given the underscore in the Class Name inside of a repository class:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Repositories;
use Acme\Models\Product\Display as Product_Display;

...

Product_Display::where('page_id','=',$page_id)->first();
```

This gives me a Class 'Acme\Models\Product\Display' not found error.
I'm guessing the problem lies in the use Acme\Models\Product\Display as Product_Display, but I've tried several variations none of which seemed to cure the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you composer dump-autoload? Do this by typing `composer dump-autoload` in the terminal from the root of your project.

Every time you make changes to your composer.json file you need to allow composer to reconstruct the autoload files. In the case of psr-0 this is all you need to do.

In the case of classmap autoloading, every time you add a file to a directory that is being autoloaded, you need to composer dump-autoload.

edit:

To fix: change `use Acme\Models\Product\Display as Product_Display;` to `use Acme\Models\Product\Display`. Change the class name from Product_Display to just Display.

I think I spotted the issue. You have `use Acme\Models\Product\Display as Product_Display;` but you need to `use Acme\Models\Product\Product_Display;` since the last part of the use statement is the name of the class. In this case your class actually is named Product_Display, not Display (which is the file name). You might also need to change the file name to match the class name (also for conventions sake you should do this).

Comment: Yes, and I have other classes included there working that lead me to believe the composer bit isn't the issue.

Comment: @cactusphone Oh, I think I spotted the issue. You have `use Acme\Models\Product\Display as Product_Display;` but you need to `use Acme\Models\Product\Product_Display;` since the last part of the use statement is the name of the class. In this case your class actually is named Product_Display, not Display (which is the file name). You might also need to change the file name to match the class name (also for conventions sake you should do this).

Comment: I've tried that: changing the filename to Product_Display.php , the class name is already `Product_Display` and changing the use statement to use `Acme\Models\Product\Product_Display as Product_Display;` I still get an error saying the class cannot be found

Comment: @cactusphone make your class name match the file name that contains it. So for example Display.php has `class Display{...}` in it. Then when you are going to use that class in another file, use the correct namespace. `use Acme\Models\Product\Display;` which was defined in `Acme/Models/Products/Display.php`.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I'll have to keep the naming conventions that way. What's puzzling to me is I can move all of these models back to the Laravel standard app/models directory and my class names with the underscores can work, ( i.e. models/product/display.php class Product_Display ) that's the only reason I thought there should be some way to make it work.

Comment: @cactusphone thats because your app/models directory is being classmap autoloaded (if you look at the default autoloading laravel's composer.json come with). Classmap autoloading doesn't care about naming conventions or namespaces. It just means "I will autoload every class and interface defined in every file in these directories". But the drawback is that you need to dump-autoload every time to add new files to those directories. (And there are other reasons psr-0 is prefered to classpmap, but I'm not the best person to answer why :) )

Answer (score 1):

You are using PSR-0 autoloading. This scheme converts every backslash and every underscore into a directory separator when building the path to the file.

So `Acme\Whatever_Underscored` is searched for in the path `prefix/Acme/Whatever/Underscored.php`.

With PSR-4, the rules have changed. First, it only works for namespaced classes, not the old `Acme_Underscore_Endless_Classnames`. Second, you don't have to have a set of otherwise emtpy directories if you don't want to. Third: Underscores are NOT converted to directory separators.

With PSR-4 rules, the `Acme\Whatever_Underscored` is searched for in the path `prefix/Acme/Whatever_Underscored.php` - or even `prefix/Whatever_Underscored.php` if configured so.

You got confused because you connected the class name in the code with the path to the file. PHP only cares about the class name in `use` imports. Always use the class name as it is defined in your class's file. Then the autoloader kicks in and tries to find a matching file - with the rules of either PSR-0 or PSR-4. If it cannot find the correct file (either the path does not point to the file correctly, or the file does not contain the class being searched for), you get an error.